# Erro no Banco de Dados API 16+

Tags: android, banco-de-dados

Bem pessoal, eu estou trabalhando na minha aplicação, e tudo estava perfeitamente bem... Tinha terminado ela com a ajuda de vocês, mas encontrei um outro problema. Eu estava testando ela no Android 2.3.3 pois ele era mais popular e abria mais rápido no meu computador, mas quando eu fui testar ele em meu tablet (que é API16) e no emulador com Android 4.1.2(API16) ele está apresentando um erro esquisito. Quando eu rodo ele no 2.3 ele abre perfeitamente, recuperando dados do BD e tudo... Entretanto, quando eu tento executá-lo numa API mais recente, me é passado que o meu Banco de Dados não existe(?!). Alguém saberia me dizer se houve alguma mudança no jeito de trabalhar com BDs internos nas APIs recentes? Me falaram que algum dos meus comandos poderia ter caído em desuso, mas o problema está apontando só pro SQL, e não pro Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stéfano, você poderia incluir os logs de erro que você obteve?

Talvez você esteja enfrentando o mesmo problema que eu tive quando testei minha app em versões 4.+, pois desenvolvi baseado na versão 2.3 também.

O problema é relacionado a como você fecha os recursos do banco de dados. Descobri, após um pouco de pesquisa, que a maneira correta de fechar os recursos é a seguinte:

Exemplo:

```java
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
// ...
}
SQLiteOpenHelper dbHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context);

// método para escrita
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
try {
    db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
    // ... executa operaçao de escrita
} finally {
    if (db != null && db.isOpen()) {
        db.close();
    }
}

// método para leitura
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
Cursor cursor = null;
try {
    db = dbHandler.getReadableDatabase();
    // ... executa operaçao de leitura com o cursor

} finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Nota: Para leitura, não se deve fechar a instância de SQLiteDatabase e não se deve fechar o SQLiteOpenHelper a cada escrita/leitura.

Se o seu problema for o mesmo que eu tive, isso irá resolver para todas as versões do android >= 2.3. Não posso te afirmar que o seu problema é esse pois não tenho os logs.

Espero ter ajudado. :)

Comment: Foi isso mesmo que deu erro! Eu olhei aqui e consegui consertar, valeu!